# Node server on OS X using computer's name instead of localhost/IP

Tags: node.js, macos, hapi.js

For some reason when I start my Node/Hapi server the address it uses my computer's name.

I.e.,
`server started on computerName:3000` instead of `server started on localhost:3000`. 
I haven't run this server in a while, so i don't exactly remember what, if anything, I changed (it would be something on my computer, it seems, since I would see any code changes in Git). How can I get it to use localhost instead?

Comment: Odds are both names are in the hosts file tied to 127.0.0.1.  Does it matter if the name is `localhost` or not, as long as it's only listening on the localhost interface?  (hint: it shouldn't.)

Comment: @Joe yeah, ideally it shouldn't, but the app I am working on fails to work because of this.

Comment: @ahota did you actually try to access it through `localhost:3000`?

Comment: @robertklep yes

Comment: also, accessing it through name:3000 fails to connect

Comment: what have you given in server.connection.host? can you post code of your main server.js